# Conformal mapping mental roadblock

Tags: complex-numbers, conformal-geometry

Given the mapping $w=\frac{z+1}{z-i}$ evaluate the images on the $w$ plane of:

$$a)\hspace{1cm} x^2  + (y - 1)^2 = 1$$
$$b)\hspace{1cm}y - x = 0$$

---

I'm completely lost here. Hit a mental roadblock trying  to solve for $z$. Kind of learning this on my own, so any pointers on bibliography is appreciated.

Comment: Do you know any general properties of fractional linear transformations (e.g., they map circles/lines to circles/lines, they're uniquely specified by the images of three points...)?

Comment: With $w=u+iv$ in $w$-plane, set $u+iv=\dfrac{x+iy+1}{x+iy-i}$ then find $u$ and $v$ in each case.

Comment: You start with a circle and a line...  also the map preserves angles...

Answer (score 0):

(a) Writing $z=a+ib$, equation $x^2+(y-1)^2=1$ is equivalent to $|z-i|=1$, i.e. (a) describes a circle with center $i$ and radius 1. Thus, each such $z$ can be written as $z=i+e^{it}$ for $t\in[0,2\pi)$. Then
\begin{align*}
\frac{z+1}{z-i}=\frac{i+e^{it}+1}{e^{it}}=ie^{-it}+1+e^{-it}=e^{-it}(i+1)+1.
\end{align*}
Since $i+1=\sqrt{2}e^{i\pi/4}$ we obtain
\begin{align*}
\frac{z+1}{z-i}=\sqrt{2}e^{i(\pi/4-t)}+1.
\end{align*}
And this is a circle with center 1 and radius $\sqrt{2}$.

(b) Writing $z=x+iy$, equation $y-x=0$ is equivalent to $z=x+ix$, which is a straight line through $0$ and $1+i$. Thus,
\begin{align*}
\left|\frac{z+1}{z-i}-(1+i)\right|^2=\left|\frac{z+1-(1+i)(z-i)}{z-i}\right|^2=\frac{|z+1-z+i-iz-1|^2}{|z-i|^2}=\frac{|1-z|^2}{|z-i|^2}=1,
\end{align*}
which shows that we again have a circle with center $1+i$ and radius 1.